# Was The Lord of the Rings an inspiration for the Regular Show Christmas Special?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, regular-show

In *Regular Show*'s fourth season, a Christmas special premiered, appropriately titled "The Christmas Special." In it, the park employees are tasked by Santa, a bearded, immortal, magic being, with destroying the Box, an item of immense power, by throwing it into a lava pit. At one point in the special, the character Muscle Man attempts to destroy the Box with a sledgehammer, which leads to his weapon being destroyed.

In *The Lord of the Rings*, a fellowship is tasked by Gandalf, a bearded, immortal, magic being, with destroying the One Ring, item of immense power by throwing it into a lava pit. At one point in *The Fellowship of the Ring*, the character Gimli attempts to destroy the Ring with an axe, which leads to his weapon being destroyed.

My question is: did JG Quintel and the creatives behind *Regular Show* ever claim to be inspired by *The Lord of the Rings* in the development of this special? In the past, *Regular Show* had done episodes with various inspirations, so I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case.

Comment: It obviously was, but I'm stuck finding a confirmation